# Change Text value after click on Parent component in Litho

Tags: android, facebook, text, click, litho

Consider I am creating a column with two text children and setting a click handler on the column view.
I want to change the value of the first text after I click the column.
How can I do that?

Comment: I figured it out, you must use @State annotation. Read the State documentation...